# Locked out of ESXI

Tags: vmware-esxi

I was not looking, and accidentally changed the management VLAN (VLAN 1) to VLAN 100. on this server, there was only one vSwitch configured. It is setup with a physical NIC (NIC 1) setup in networking. The vSwitch is connected to ESXi via NIC 1. I can't log back in to ESXi, and that was the only connection I had to ESXi. Any ideas how to restore it back to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconfigure the main vmk vlan setting using the console GUI. Hopefully you have either physical access to the server or some other means of accessing the console.

Comment: But I bet the OP _doesn't_ have console access or out-of-band ILO/IPMI/DRAC capability...

Comment: @ewwhite I'm not going to bet against that.

Comment: Which means that it's probably a hosted ESXi server; something that doesn't make any sense to me. A very shaky combination.